# Regression With Additive Gaussian Noise

Tags: probability, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am studying Machine Learning through Prof. Ng's Stanford lectures. In lecture 3 ([lecture notes](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes1.pdf)) he models the output variable $Y$ and input variable $X$ with parameters $\theta$ as

$$Y = \theta^T X + \epsilon \tag{1}$$

where $\epsilon$ is a Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. He says that this implies that the probability distribution of $Y$ conditional on $X$ is

$$Y\mid X ;\theta\sim G(\theta^Tx, \sigma^2)$$

I cannot come up with a rigorous proof of the above. I intuitively understand that if $Y$ is conditioned on $X$, then we can treat $X$ as constant in equation $(1)$, and we can treat $Y$ as the sum of a Gaussian and a constant, which will be also be Gaussian.

Is there a more formal proof of the statement?

Comment: The formal proof is essentially encapsulated in what you've just said. You just need to expand on the definition of "conditioning $Y$ on $X,\theta$", which is unfortunately somewhat technical even though it expresses a simple, intuitive concept. (To be specific, the rigorous definition requires the introduction of an additional $\sigma$-algebra which in general is a strict subset of the one used to define the underlying probability space.) Look up "conditional expectation" for details.

Comment: Thank you! I take that it would not be possible to prove $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac {f_{X.Y}(x, y)} {f_X(x)} = f_{\epsilon}(y-x) $ using just algebraic manipulation and calculus (i.e. without resorting to $\sigma$-algebra) ?

Comment: In the continuous context there might be a way to do marginalization explicitly rather than needing to formally define conditional expectation.